# Decrementing a value and wrapping back to a max value without using if statement?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, decrement

Incrementing and wrapping back to zero is easy:

```
i = (i + 1) % Max;
```

But decrementing is not as straight forward. Basically to decrement and wrap you usually find code like this:

```
i--;
if (i < 0)
   i = Max;
```

How can we write the previous code without using if statements?

I know that probably bit-wise operators will be involved. Usually when I'm faced with such problems I try to come up with some equations with two terms A and B, then try to find the actual values of these two terms. For example:

```
i = A + B
```

if `i` was in the range `]0, Max]` then we'd get:

`i = 0 + B` and `B = i-1`

otherwise if `i == 0`:

`i = A + 0` and `A = Max`

similarly we can write:

```
i = i == 0 ? Max : i - 1;
```

How to write the previous equation without any ifs or ternary operators? I tried so many bit-wise operations and different arithmetic combos but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Umm, no? that doesn't work. Say `Max = 10` and `i = 0`, then `i = -1 % 10 `that's still equal to `-1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
i = (Max-1 + i)%Max
```

will work as long as `0<=i<Max`.

Comment: This may overflow if Max > INTMAX/2, but is good for smaller Max values

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I wanted to wrap back to `Max`, this wraps to `Max - 1`. But considering that most the usage cases are for indices decrementing, usually the max is the count of the array and we want to wrap back to count-1, in that case this works perfectly. I tried to modify your code to wrap to `Max` by adding + 1 to the entire result, but now it doesn't decrement `i` when `0 < i < Max`

Comment: Sorry, my answer is the exact decrement analog of your increment example, `(i+1)%Max`.  Reading the rest of your post more carefully, it looks like what you want is `(Max-i)%(Max+1)`, that is you want to cycle through the `Max+1` values Max, Max-1, ..., 0, Max, Max-1, ...

Comment: @Chris Dodd Yes, it's also probably slower than the ternary operator code the OP presents, unless Max (or is it Max+1) is a power of two..

Comment: May I ask you to explain your logical thought process when you wrote the answers? In other words, how did you come up with them?

Comment: And yeah you're right. It's almost 3 times slower. Wonder if there's a faster way without the module. Still interested in knowing how you come up with the answers and your thought process.

Comment: @vexe: this is just `i = (i - 1) mod Max`, the problem being that C's `%` operator is remainder rather than modulus, so you need to correct the range to positive by adding `Max`.  As for slowness, its just as slow as your "increment and wrap" -- that is also much faster to do with a conditional.

Comment: Thanks. Right so we could have also written `i = (i - 1 + Max) % Max;` which is a bit clearer imho. What about the `(Max-i) % (Max+i)`? what's the logic behind that?

Comment: `Max` is congruent to `-1` modulo `Max+1`, just as `Max-1` is congruent to `-1` modulo `Max`.  But I should have been cleverer and noticed the objection Chris Dodd raised.  The workaround for that is `i=Max-1-(Max-i)%Max`. Just leave off the `%Max` to see that it usually gives `Max-1-(Max-i)` equals `i-1`, and check that when `i==0` it wraps correctly.

Comment: The real point is that the % operator is extremely slow -- much slower than a multiply.  Although branching can be slow, in this case the condition is trivial as are both branches -- the ternary operator will beat any expression with `%` in it for either incrementing or decrementing.  The only exception is if `Max` is a power of two, in which case `(i-1)&(Max-1)` is the same thing as `(Max-1-i)%Max` and will also beat the ternary expression.

Comment: One more arcane point: Although `(-1)%10` equals `-1` for every C compiler I've ever used, the ISO C standard does not guarantee this.  A fully conforming implementation of C could return `9`, in other words `%` could be the mathematical modulo operation -- as long as `(-1)/10` returned `-1` (instead of `0` as it does for every C compiler I know).  In other words, you should not write a C program which requires `(-1)%10` to be `-1` (or `(-1)/10` to be `0`)in order to work properly.

Answer (score -1):

you can modify it to fit the range you need

```js
var offset, 
    max = 10, 
    str = '', 
    counter = document.getElementById('counter');

for(var i = 0; i < (max * max); i++){
  offset = ((max + i) % max);
  str += (max - offset)+"<br/>";
}

counter.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id='counter'></div>
```

Comment: Umm, could you explain how this works? Looks to me that `(max+i) % max` is just `i % max` which gives the same values for the loop variable `i`, so `offset = i` and then `max - offset` is `max - i`. if I change `i < Max*Max` to `i < Max` and `offset = i` I would get the same output. Sorry not seeing how this helps maybe I'm missing something obvious. I like the "Run code snippet" feature this is the first time I see it!